# Roots growing up in newly potted propagate

Tags: containers, propagation, repotting, figs

I tried propagating my first plant: a fiddle leaf fig. I propagated in water and when roots were about 2  or 3 inches I put it in a pot with soil. I noticed some roots started showing above the soil. Is this bad?

The potting soil was quite dry from sitting in my garage for about a year. I watered it frequently for a few days (because I thought since it had been in water so long that's what it would like), to the point the water spilled over the saucer a bit. I stopped watering it so frequently (but the soil on top is not dry).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How long since you potted it?

Comment: Like 6 or 7 days I think (those leaves are not new)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd remove the lowest leaf which is sitting against the soil already and is discoloured at the base, then top up with a little potting soil just to cover the roots thinly, but don't add any more if they reappear at some point. Also check the tightness of the tie you've used to support the stem - I can't really tell properly, but it looks like it might be a little too tight, and over time the stem needs to thicken up a bit and you don't want the tie to prevent that.

Comment: I ended up added just a little bit more soil on top and they haven't reappeared so all seems good! I ended up taking off the twist tie and support stick for now.

Answer (score 1):

The new roots will keep growing until they hit the inside of the pot. You can:

- do nothing
- add some soil
- or cut the growing tip off with a sharp knife to encourage